# Large abelian subgroups of perfect groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, simple-groups

It is not too hard to prove that if $G$ is a non-abelian finite simple group and $A \leqslant G$ is an abelian subgroup, then  $|A| \leq \sqrt{|G|}$ (this can be improved to $\ll |G|^{1/3}$ using the classification). There exists a similar bound for $G$ being perfect?

In particular, can the index $[G:A]$ be fixed while $G$ grows in this case?

Comment: Your questions are in opposite direction: Derek's answer shows that the answer is "no" for the first and "yes" for the second (namely there exist arbitrary large finite perfect groups with an abelian normal subgroup of index 60).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such bound, and yes $|G:A|$ can be fixed while $|G|$ grows.

Let $S$ be a finite simple group, and $M$ a faithful irreducible module for $S$ over a finite field. For example, we could take $S = A_5$ and $M$ the $4$-dimensional deleted permutation module over the field of prime order $p$ for any $p \ne 5$ (or the $3$-dimensional module when $p=5$).

Now let $G$ be the semidirect product $A \rtimes S$, where $A$ is the direct sum of $k$ copies of $M$ for any $k > 0$. Then $G$ is perfect with abelian normal subgroup $A$ of order $|M|^k$ with $|G:A| = |S|$.